# How to run a Monte Carlo simulation to produce the most likely top rated product in R?

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm looking to run a Monte Carlo simulation on some grouped data to see which product is most likely to be rated top through 10,000 iterations. I have a dataframe that contains the columns product, group and rating. For each group, I'd like to simulate the rating 10,000 times based on the rating equalling the mean and standard deviation equalling 0.57. All ratings range between 2 and 10. I'd then like to summarise the instances of which product is 1st to establish the probability of of each product being top rated. I rerun this code maybe weekly as the ratings are updated and my full dataframe can have 250 rows.

I've used the below code through trawling through various websites but running it brings up the error at the bottom. I don't think the code is giving me the right data but the error coming from running the simulations line after the first function stops me from kicking on to check.

My ideal output is to have the product and probability of being top rated is possible.

```
df <- data.frame(product = c("Product1", "Product2", "Product3"), rating = c(3, 5, 6.4))
num_sims <- 10000
monte_carlo <- function(row, num_sims) {
  product <- row[1]
  rating <- row[2]
  outcomes <- rnorm(num_sims, mean = rating, sd = 0.57)
    return(data.frame(product = product, rating = rating, outcomes = outcomes))
}
simulations <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) monte_carlo(df[i,], num_sims))

simulations_df <- do.call(rbind, simulations)

simulations_df$outcomes <- unlist(simulations_df$outcomes)
```

Error in rnorm(num_sims, mean = rating, sd = 0.57) : invalid arguments

Comment: Use `product <- row[[1]]` and `rating <- row[[2]]` with double braces to extract the numeric value form the data.frame row.